# Playwrigth goTo with waitting for response of enpoint which fire to bring main content

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, playwright

I want always after to go to some react page to wait for initial content load (content from endpoint) and I wonder which way will be stable to do that. I also always safe the response for later test based on body.

```
await page.goto(myUrl)
await page.waitForResponse("/myendpoint")
/* or */
await Promise.all([
 page.goto(myUrl)
 page.waitForResponse("/myendpoint")
])
```

Comment: Your second version doesn't work like you think. If you use `Promise.all()` you should remove the `await`s from inside the array, otherwise it behaves just like the first version. After fixing that issue, probably the second one is what you want to avoid a race condition, but it depends on when the response is received by the target page.

Comment: I edited that, my fault, it shouldnt be there

Comment: Yes I am wondering if its stable 100%, request is fire to bring content after site start to render (React Application), so depends on internet it can start imeddiatly after recive scripts or has a bit delay